# Third Order Linear Nonhomogeneous Differential Equation with Variable Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation:

$(x^2-1)F''' + 2\left(x-\frac{1-x^2}{x}\right)F'' + \left(2+\frac{x^2}{2(1-x^2)}+\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}\right)\left(F'-\frac{F}{x}\right) = A \left(2 + \frac{x^2}{2(1-x^2)} \right)$

where A is a constant, and $x \in  [0,1]$. I'm getting a bit discouraged to be honest.
Any idea/suggestion would be most welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $F=xu$ ,

Then $F'=xu'+u$

$F''=xu''+u'+u'=xu''+2u'$

$F'''=xu'''+u''+2u''=xu'''+3u''$

$\therefore(x^2-1)(xu'''+3u'')+2\left(x-\dfrac{1-x^2}{x}\right)(xu''+2u')+\left(2+\dfrac{x^2}{2(1-x^2)}+\dfrac{1-x^2}{x^2}\right)(xu'+u-u)=A\left(2+\dfrac{x^2}{2(1-x^2)}\right)$

$x(x^2-1)u'''+3(x^2-1)u''+2(2x^2-1)u''+4\left(2x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)u'+\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{2(x^2-1)}\right)xu'=A\left(\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2(x^2-1)}\right)$

$x(x^2-1)u'''+(7x^2-5)u''+\left(\dfrac{17x}{2}-\dfrac{3}{x}-\dfrac{x}{2(x^2-1)}\right)u'=A\left(\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2(x^2-1)}\right)$

$u'''+\dfrac{7x^2-5}{x(x^2-1)}u''+\left(\dfrac{17}{2(x^2-1)}-\dfrac{3}{x^2(x^2-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2(x^2-1)^2}\right)u'=A\left(\dfrac{3}{2x(x^2-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2x(x^2-1)^2}\right)$

Let $v=\dfrac{du}{dx}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}+\dfrac{7x^2-5}{x(x^2-1)}\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\left(\dfrac{17}{2(x^2-1)}-\dfrac{3}{x^2(x^2-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2(x^2-1)^2}\right)v=A\left(\dfrac{3}{2x(x^2-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2x(x^2-1)^2}\right)$

Let $r=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dv}{dr}$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(2x\dfrac{dv}{dr}\right)=2x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dr}\right)+2\dfrac{dv}{dr}=2x\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{dv}{dr}\right)\dfrac{dr}{dx}+2\dfrac{dv}{dr}=2x\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}2x+2\dfrac{dv}{dr}=4x^2\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dv}{dr}=4r\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dv}{dr}$

$\therefore4r\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\dfrac{14r-10}{r-1}\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\left(\dfrac{17}{2(r-1)}-\dfrac{3}{r(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2(r-1)^2}\right)v=A\left(\dfrac{3}{2\sqrt r(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt r(r-1)^2}\right)$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}+\left(\dfrac{1}{2r}+\dfrac{7r-5}{2r(r-1)}\right)\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\left(\dfrac{17}{8r(r-1)}-\dfrac{3}{4r^2(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{8r(r-1)^2}\right)v=A\left(\dfrac{3}{8r\sqrt r(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{8r\sqrt r(r-1)^2}\right)$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}+\left(\dfrac{3}{r}+\dfrac{1}{r-1}\right)\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\left(\dfrac{3}{4r^2}+\dfrac{3}{2r(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{8(r-1)^2}\right)v=\dfrac{A}{2(r-1)\sqrt r}-\dfrac{A}{8(r-1)^2\sqrt r}-\dfrac{A}{2r\sqrt r}$

Let $v=r^a(r-1)^bw$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dr}=r^a(r-1)^b\dfrac{dw}{dr}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a}{r}+\dfrac{b}{r-1}\right)w$

$\dfrac{d^2v}{du^2}=r^a(r-1)^b\dfrac{d^2w}{dr^2}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a}{r}+\dfrac{b}{r-1}\right)\dfrac{dw}{dr}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a}{r}+\dfrac{b}{r-1}\right)\dfrac{dw}{dr}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a(a-1)}{r^2}+\dfrac{2ab}{r(r-1)}+\dfrac{b(b-1)}{(r-1)^2}\right)w=r^a(r-1)^b\dfrac{d^2w}{dr^2}+2r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a}{r}+\dfrac{b}{r-1}\right)\dfrac{dw}{dr}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a(a-1)}{r^2}+\dfrac{2ab}{r(r-1)}+\dfrac{b(b-1)}{(r-1)^2}\right)w$

$\therefore r^a(r-1)^b\dfrac{d^2w}{dr^2}+2r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a}{r}+\dfrac{b}{r-1}\right)\dfrac{dw}{dr}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a(a-1)}{r^2}+\dfrac{2ab}{r(r-1)}+\dfrac{b(b-1)}{(r-1)^2}\right)w+\left(\dfrac{3}{r}+\dfrac{1}{r-1}\right)\left(r^a(r-1)^b\dfrac{dw}{dr}+r^a(r-1)^b\left(\dfrac{a}{r}+\dfrac{b}{r-1}\right)w\right)+\left(\dfrac{3}{4r^2}+\dfrac{3}{2r(r-1)}-\dfrac{1}{8(r-1)^2}\right)r^a(r-1)^bw=\dfrac{A}{2(r-1)\sqrt r}-\dfrac{A}{8(r-1)^2\sqrt r}-\dfrac{A}{2r\sqrt r}$

$\dfrac{d^2w}{dr^2}+\left(\dfrac{2a+3}{r}+\dfrac{2b+1}{r-1}\right)\dfrac{dw}{dr}+\left(\dfrac{4a^2+8a+3}{4r^2}+\dfrac{2ab+a+3b+3}{r(r-1)}+\dfrac{8b^2-1}{8(r-1)^2}\right)w=\dfrac{A}{2r^a(r-1)^{b+1}\sqrt r}-\dfrac{A}{8r^a(r-1)^{b+2}\sqrt r}-\dfrac{A}{2r^{a+1}(r-1)^b\sqrt r}$

Choose $4a^2+8a+3=0$ and $8b^2-1=0$ , and the ODE reduces to Gaussian hypergeometric equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried it but I didn't go all the way to F(x). Instead, I feel like F(x) could be expressed as an integral functional of $A x$ as it has been done for a very similar differential equation in my field (Friedlander 1976).